# What is a good way to join all connected relational tables in a database?

Tags: python, sql-server, join, graph

**I have tried following approaches**

- Topological sort to find table dependencies to
  programatically create join queries
- BFS to order tables in such a way that join query can be formed

But in both the approaches I am getting stuck in an edge case, where one of the tables is being joined before its' dependent table is joined.

In the below schema dependency diagram,

[image: Sample Schema]

Each arrow is pointing towards a table which has foreign key reference to the given table, for example table sheep has 2 foreign keys one for Pet and one for Livestock.

**I want to join all the tables into a de-normalised single view.**

**My above two approaches fail** in this case because with topological sort my script will try to join Table Bird with table Animal even before it will join table chicken, so it will result in an error.

With BFS approach I can traverse the first half of the graph easily and in right order, but the problem will occur when I need to traverse the second half (table Bird and Eagle) there is no trivial way to select Bird table before Eagle table.

One approach I am planning to try is to make the above schema un-directed, in that case I will be able to traverse in the required order. But I think there will be some edge case where this approach might also fail.

Are there any known methods to achieve this? or if not what should be a good approach to do it.

I am using MSSQL, and my current scripts are in python.

Comment: Please give your design so we can talk clearly & precisely about variations on your design & about using designs. PS Constraints ("table dependencies") (including FKs & CKs) are not needed to query. (They imply that some queries always return the same result that otherwise wouldn't, so they do allow us more flexibility in writing queries.) The lines in your picture do not represent FKs, they represent subrows in tables. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. (So here the diagram is useful in addition to a text form of it but give the text form.)